# Is it possible to have $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{\|g h_n\|_1}{\|h_n\|_1}=\infty$?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Is it possible to have $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{\|g h_n\|_1}{\|h_n\|_1}=\infty$?

Consider a metric space $(\Xi, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ and $g$ and $\{h_n\}_n$ non negative, measurable functions in this space. Consider then the norm
$$\|g\|_1 = \int_{\Xi} |g(\omega)| d\nu(\omega)$$

and that

- $\|g\|_1<\infty$,
- $\|h_n\|_1<\infty \, \forall n$,
- $h_n\leq 1$, so we have that $\|gh_n\|_1\leq 1 \, \forall n.$
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|h_n\|=0$

My question is, assuming that $g$ doesn't depend on $n$, is it possible to have
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{\|gh_n\|_1}{\|h_n\|_1}=\infty?$$

The result is true if $g$ and $h_n$ were uncorrelated, or at least negativelly correlated (that is, $\|gh_n\|_1\leq \|g\|_1\|h_n\|_1$). But I was wondering if the fact $g$ doesn't depend on $n$ is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will consider the space $[0,1]$.  The function
$g(x) = x^{-1/2}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, so $\|g\|_1 < \infty$.  Let $h_n$ be the indicator function for the interval $[0,n^{-1}]$.  Then $h_n\leq 1$ and $\|h_n\|_1 = 1/n \to 0$.  On the other hand,
$$
\|gh_n\|_1 = \int_0^{n^{-1}} x^{-1/2} \,dx \geq n^{-1/2},
$$
since $x^{-1/2}>n^{1/2}$ for $x\in[0,n^{-1}]$.  Therefore $\frac{\|gh_n\|}{\|h_n\|}\geq n^{1/2}$, which diverges to $+\infty$.